# Loading image from program arguments

Tags: java, image, processing

Hi for some reason this won't load my image.  If anyone has any help it would be much appreciated.  It has to do with the stirng fn = args[0]; but I cannot figure it out.  Thank you!

```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  public class ImageProc
  {
    public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String fn = args[0];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Image Processing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MainPanel panel = new MainPanel("flower.jpg"); 

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

Comment: (1) Why do you think it has to do with `fn = args[0]`?  (2) "Won't load my image" isn't enough of an explanation.  Can you tell us the program's behavior, or is it a secret?

Comment: If you post the error message it's giving you, that might help.

Comment: the error I get is 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you're not passing any arguments to the program (use `System.out.println("Arguments = " + args.length);` to see what I mean)

Comment: Question titles should NOT be upper cased!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hardcoded the filename (`fn`) and you aren't calling the program with any command line arguments. I would suggest you use

```
String fn = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "flower.jpg";
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Image Processing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// MainPanel panel = new MainPanel("flower.jpg");
MainPanel panel = new MainPanel(fn);
```

That way you can provide command line arguments later (if you want) and the program checks if they are present first.

Alternatively, you could comment out

```
// String fn = args[0];
```

the reason that `args[0]` fails is because you aren't running your program with command line arguments.

Finally, you could run your existing code if you provided a command line argument.